# How to catch all routes starting with admin

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3

In my vuejs 3 application, I'm trying to add a navigation drawer to all admin routes. So, I need to catch all routes starting with admin (this includes "/admin", "/admin/users", "/admin/users/10" etc). I tried "/admin*", not working. I've tried googling around, no solution too.

Comment: How about getting the current route, extract the first 6 characters and check if this extracted string is equal to '/admin' then you could symply return true or false from that function... with that in mind you could just use a v-if in your navigation drawer and it will only be rendered when the route starts with admin.

Answer (score 0):

**One possible approach:**

In the component where you render the navigation drawer, you could extract the route path portion that you need and then check if the current route is allowed to render the navigation drawer:

So you could create a function like this:

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
const route = useRoute()

//We will pass a parameter to reuse the function in case you need it.
const routeIsAllowed = (requiredRoute) => {
  const routePath = route.path.substring(0, requiredRoute.lenght);
  return routePath === requiredRoute
}
```

Then in your `template` you just render conditionally based on the route path name matching your criteria:

```
<NavigationDrawer v-if="routeIsAllowed('/admin')" />
```

There might be a different approach but I think is a valid solution with reutilization in mind.

Also if you want to get an array of routes in a nested route configuration in Vue Router, you just need to get it like this:

full route path: `/admin/users`

```
route.matched[0].path // '/admin'
route.matched[1].path // '/users'
```

Basically `matched` will give you an array of each route path, which can be accessed with the index value and `.path` at the end as a string.